# Perfect number table below 9999, does not show correct?

Tags: java

When I run eclipse the result it shows me are

```
0
6
28
240
496
1344
8128
```

The expected results are:

```
6
28
496
8128
```

Why does my code print 0, 240, and 1344?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Chapter5Exercise11isPerfect extends ConsoleProgram{
    public void run (){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9999; i++){
            int k = 0;
            for (int s = 1; s <=i/2; s++){
                if (i%s ==0){
                    k=k+s;
                }
            }
            if (k%i==0){
                println (k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I am really grateful for corrections you gave me!! I will try to manage my question better.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's very simple, from Wikipedia:

> **In number theory, a perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper positive divisors**, that is, the sum of its positive divisors excluding the number itself (also known as its aliquot sum). Equivalently, a perfect number is a number that is half the sum of all of its positive divisors (including itself) i.e. σ1(n) = 2n.

Your condition is wrong:

```
if (k%i==0)
```

You need to check if `k` and `i` are equal:

```
if (k == i)
```

Change that in your code and let me know if it works.

Comment: omg it work. My happiness is up to max :D. Thanks for help GCP!

Comment: @NikolaJovanovic Consider marking the answer as useful by ticking the "correct" arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: I am buddy. I tried few times. And it give me "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". Do I have to do something?

Comment: hahahahahaha. I am so new :D